# Generate unique short slug for post entries (like 9gag)

Tags: php, cakephp

9gag has :

http://9gag.com/gag/amXB20o

I want the same, something like:

http://mysite.com/post/{shortslug}

How can I generate short (8-10 chars ?)  **unique** slugs for each post when I save them ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

EDIT : I though about using md5 of the Id but the hash is way too long.

Comment: php's `uniqid()` function might work. Generate the unique ID, then shorten it to your string length, but before saving, check if the ID is already exists in your DB or not, if it does not, then save it, else, generate a new one and repeat.

Comment: Do you actually have a business need to use random alpha-numeric characters for a post identifier rather than the standard, search engine-friendly URL; or are you just wanting to do it because that site does it?

Comment: What research did you do? Since there are a lot of topics about this. [example](http://kvz.io/blog/2009/06/10/create-short-ids-with-php-like-youtube-or-tinyurl/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$key = substr(md5(rand(1,999999)), 0, 10);
echo $key;
```

Then check if that exists, if it doesn't just generate another one

On a SEO note, I would have the url as `www.example.com/post/5245/this-is-an-example-title/` and just use the id in the database with auto increment